# Wait not working to sync three processes

Tags: c, unix, ipc, wait

Im a new C dev. I'm trying to sync three processes to print [FATHER][SON][GRANDSON][FATHER][SON][GRANDSON] with this code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    int c = 0;
    while (c<2)
    {
        c++;
        printf("[FATHER]");
        pid_t son = fork();
        if (son == 0)
        {
            printf("[SON]");
            pid_t grandson = fork();
            if (grandson == 0)
            {
                printf("[GRANDSON]");
                return 0;
            }
            wait(NULL);
            return 0;
        }
        wait(NULL);
    };

  }
```

Instead, im getting this output: [FATHER][SON][GRANDSON][FATHER][SON][FATHER][FATHER][SON][GRANDSON][FATHER][FATHER][SON][FATHER][FATHER]

Am i misunderstanding or missing something when using wait on code? Thank you very very much.

Comment: Try flushing the stream, `fflush( stdout )`, see if that helps.

Comment: Or write to stderr directly like `fprintf (stderr, "[FATHER]");`.

Comment: K-ballo It works perfectly after using fflush after every printf. Thak you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling `fflush` after every call to `printf`, it'd be better if you used the `write` system call to print to `stdout` (format the output string using `sprintf` first if necessary). The `write` system call does unbuffered writing, which would prevent you from having to remember to call `fflush` every time.

You could even use a variadic macro to avoid writing always a `sprintf` line followed by a `write` line.

Comment: Ill investigate what you proposed. TBH, ive never used variadic macros on C :)